# Trying to get reviews for a specfic game

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, link-to

Im attempting to see reviews for a specific game that ive created.  Right now my reviews/index show for all games, not just the specific game im looking for.  Im assuming its just something im missing in my params but not sure...

these my are controllers...

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except:[:index, :show]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @reviews = Review.all
  end

  def show
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  end 
...
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_game, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 
  def index
    @games = Game.all
  end


  def show
  end
```

my routes ...

```
reviews#index
                                      POST   /games/:game_id/reviews(.:format)                                                        reviews#create
                      new_game_review GET    /games/:game_id/reviews/new(.:format)                                                    reviews#new
                     edit_game_review GET    /games/:game_id/reviews/:id/edit(.:format)                                               reviews#edit
                          game_review GET    /games/:game_id/reviews/:id(.:format)                                                    reviews#show
                                      PATCH  /games/:game_id/reviews/:id(.:format)                                                    reviews#update
                                      PUT    /games/:game_id/reviews/:id(.:format)                                                    reviews#update
                                      DELETE /games/:game_id/reviews/:id(.:format)                                                    reviews#destroy
                                games GET    /games(.:format)                                                                         games#index
                                      POST   /games(.:format)                                                                         games#create
                             new_game GET    /games/new(.:format)                                                                     games#new
                            edit_game GET    /games/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                games#edit
                                 game GET    /games/:id(.:format)                                                                     games#show
                                      PATCH  /games/:id(.:format)                                                                     games#update
                                      PUT    /games/:id(.:format)                                                                     games#update
                                      DELETE /games/:id(.:format)                                                                     games#destroy
                                 root GET    /                                                                                        games#index
```

this is how im attempting to do my link_to but its showing all the games reviews in my seeds not just a single game and all its reviews...

```
<%= link_to 'reviews', game_reviews_path(game_id: @game.id), @reviews %>
```

first RoR prj on my own, any help would be great!!

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is not working is because you are not using the `game_id` you are passing to the ReviewsController. You need to query for Reviews belonging to the specific Game.

```
def index
  @reviews = Review.where(game_id: params[:game_id]).all
end
```